# I had breakfast before I do exercise? Correct to say?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct?
If not...
I guess 'did' instead of 'do' will  be the better choice, but I just wonder if that sentence above can be used in the following situation.

It's 8 a.m right now. I haven't started doing exercise yet and  am about to do exercise in 10 min.  I had breakfast 30 minutes ago.

In that case, I don't think I can use the past tense 'did' cause I am not done any exercise yet .
Can you help me with the sentence? Thank you so much in advance..

Comment: Your problem is the use of "before"; I can't think of any way where you can use this mixing past and future. Instead you'd be looking for something like "I have had breakfast but I haven't done any exercise yet."

Comment: Or *I had breakfast* ***and I will*** *(do) exercise*.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on your view of the situation.
1. I would say:
'I have had (or: l've had) breakfast before I do exercise' if you consider the whole situation referring to the daily routine. Then 'having breakfast' must be in the Present Perfect Tense to show the completed event (having breakfast) with the present result ( now you aren't hungry and are free to do smth else).
2. When you use the Past Simple Tense you refer 'having breakfast' to the completed past event (yesterday or 30 minutes ago).
Then you can say about the present (current) situation: 'I had breakfast 30 minutes ago, and now I'm going to do exercise'.

Comment: "I have had breakfast before I do the exercises" is not idiomatic.

Answer (score -3):

"I have breakfast before I do exercise."  This is present tense, which happens daily in your routine life.

"I had breakfast before I do exercise."  This sentence appears to be wrong.  This can be written as

"I had breakfast before my exercise." This is past tense.

Comment: "I had breakfast before my exercise" does not convey that the exercise is in the future; it implies it is in the past.

Comment: I have breakfast before I do exercise." This is present tense, which happens daily in your routine life.

Comment: OP wants a phrase that means "*It's 8 a.m right now. I haven't started doing exercise yet and am about to do exercise in 10 min. I had breakfast 30 minutes ago.*". None of your phrases cover this, and therefore they don't answer the question. Please note that on all stack exchange sites, what you write in the Answer box must answer the Question.